# Clipping raster with polygon mask but keeping outer edge cells of mask in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, clip, masking

In QGIS, how to clip a raster with a polygon mask, but keep the outer edge cells of the raster touching the mask?

In other words: how to create a one raster cell outer buffer for the masking polygon?

Comment: It's probably much easier just to run the **buffer** tool on the polygon mask layer and increase the extent of that.

Comment: @Joseph but you'd have to buffer it by the diagonal of a cell to catch cells that just touch the polygon by a corner, and that size buffer would also catch cells that don't touch the polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it by creating a buffer first as @Joseph suggested. To get buffer:

```
ogr2ogr.exe "\"[temporary file]\"" 1402.shp 1402 -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Buffer( geometry , 0.001 ),* FROM '1402' "
```

where, 1402.shp is my mask shapefile and 0.001 is my buffer distance.